# I can't understand how this function works (linear filter with a filter kernel)

Tags: linear, kernel-smoothing, filter

on page 13 of the Dayan and Abbott [book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262041997/theoretical-neuroscience/) onTheoretical Neuroscience, there is this formula

$$r_{approx}(t)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{d\tau w(\tau) \rho(t-\tau)}$$

Let's assume that $w(t)$ is a gaussian function. This is called a linear filter and apparently it generates a nice smooth function of individual events in timeassume that $w(t)$ is a gaussian function. Here, $\rho(t)= \sum_{i=1}^n\delta(t-t_i)$, where $t_i=1, ...,n $ is a sequence of times at which an event (a neuron spike) occurred.

My understanding is that $\rho$ is always going to be zero but at $t$ *if* a spike occurred at $t$, in which case is gonna be $1$.
Consequently, since $\rho(t-\tau) \neq 0 $ only when $t = \tau$, the integral disappears everywhere but at $t=\tau$ and thus we have $r_{approx}(t) = w(t)$.

I don't see how this function can smooth out the input spike train since this is just a gaussian function, and is only a function of time. I probably did an error in my reasoning, but where is it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively your integral will become a sum of Gaussian functions

$$r_{approx}(t)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ w(\tau) \rho(t-\tau)} d\tau = \sum_{i=1}^n w(t-t_i)
$$

whenever $t-\tau = t_i$ the value of $\rho(t-\tau)$ hits a spike for one of the $\delta$ functions and gives a value of one when you integrate over it.

Comment: This was enough for me to get it. I clearly got confused with the meaning of $\rho(t-\tau)$. Thanks!